# Clipping a ggmap object by an sf object

Tags: r, clip, sf, ggmap

Is there a way to clip a ggmap object by an sf object?

1. I have a Google Earth satellite image that I have pulled using ggmaps:

```
gmap<- get_map(location=c(lat = mylat, lon = mylon ), zoom=15, maptype = 'satellite', source = 'google')
```

2. I have managed to plot both the sf object and the Google Earth image together using the following code:

```
plot(st_transform(st_geometry(sf object), crs = 3857)[1], bgMap = gmap)
```

This yields the following plot:
[image]

I have spent several hours trying, unsuccessfully, to perform either of the following operations.

A) plot the gmap object first, then add the sf object on top. The effect of this would be to zoom in on the gmap object and allow the portion of the sf line that runs through it to be seen clearly.

B) clip the gmap object using the sf object (i.e. so the portion of the gmap object outside the sf object is removed).

Comment: You can do it by creating a `terra` package raster of the same shape as the `ggmap` object (which is just a matrix with some extra attributes), then use `terra::mask` to cut out from that, then use that mask to set values in the map to NA. I've just spent half an hour working this out to find that `ggmap` stores its matrix the "wrong" way round compared to `terra` and I've no time to get it right now. But that's my outline solution. The real solution is to drop `ggmap` and get the basemap raster using a modern package that returns standard R spatial data structures.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a go at your workaround - do you know of any more modern packages that allow you to pull UK satellite image data?

Comment: The off-CRAN package `poisspatial` has a function `ps_ggmap_to_raster` to convert `ggmap` objects to `raster` - also has some other basemap functions that might do the business directly. https://github.com/poissonconsulting/poisspatial